# Iterate over dates pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
        CITY        DT         Error%
1        A      1/1/2020     0.03436722
2        A      1/2/2020     0.03190177
3        B      1/9/2020     0.040218757
4        B      1/8/2020     0.098921665
```

I want to iterate through the dataframe and check if the DT and its next week DT have a ERROR % of less than 0.05.

I want the return to be the dataframe series

```
    2        A      1/2/2020     0.03190177
    3        B      1/9/2020     0.040218757
```

Comment: @jezrael I want to return both that day and its next week so 1/2/2020 and 1/9/2020 since both have error less than 5%

Comment: Do I have you right that you want to filter the dataframe for rows, where `Error% < 0.05` for `DT` and `DT + 7 days` or the same holds for `DT` and `DT - 7 days`?

Comment: @LukasThaler only for DT and DT+7 days

Comment: Why would you return row 3 then? There's no entry for 1/16/2020

Comment: @LukasThaler because 1/2/2020 and plus 7 days== 1/2/2020 have the error less than 5%

Comment: Okay, so you want both rows returned for any pair of dates that matches the error condition?

Comment: and the pair should be +7 days apart like Monday with next Monday

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206797/discussion-between-lukas-thaler-and-ubuntu-noob).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DT'])

idx = df[df['DT'].sub(df['DT'].shift()).gt('6 days')].index.tolist()

indices = []

for i in idx:
    indices.append(i-1)
    indices.append(i)
```

---

```
print(df.loc[df['Error%'] <= 0.05].loc[indices])
   CITY         DT    Error%
2    A 2020-01-02  0.031902
3    B 2020-01-09  0.040219
```

Comment: why shift 6 days?

Comment: @ubuntu_noob it's not shifting 6 days, it's shifting by one row and measuring the distance, if it's greater than 6 days, i.e one week then we have a match. the next filter is for 0.05%

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly elegant, but it gets the job done and maybe some of the professionals here can improve on it:

First, merge the information for the day with the info for the day a week after by performing a self-join on the time-shifted `DT` column. we can use an inner join since we're only interested in rows that have an entry for the week after:

```py
tmp = df.set_index(df.DT.apply(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta('7 days'))) \
          .join(df.set_index('DT'), lsuffix='_L', how='inner')
```

Then select the date column for those entries where both error margins are satisfied:

```py
tmp = tmp.DT.loc[(tmp['Error%_L'] < 0.05) & (tmp['Error%'] < 0.05)]
```

`tmp` is now a `pd.Series` with information in the index (the shifted values) and the values (the first week). Since both dates are wanted in the output, compile the "index dates" by taking the unique values among all of them:

```py
idx = list(set(tmp.tolist() + tmp.index.tolist()))
```

And finally, grab the corresponding rows from the original dataframe:

```py
df.set_index('DT').loc[idx].reset_index()
```

This, however loses you the original row number. If that is needed, you'll have to save it to a column first and reset the index back to that variable after selecting the relevant rows